# Mac Desktop Version

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way to set a version number for Mac OS Desktop apps in CN1? It always shows 1.0 no matter what I write in build.xml.

I can't find any build hint that could help either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a problem here, we'll fix it for the coming update so the version from the Codename One Settings app will be respected.